# React app won't connect to django-rest database

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm to update the frontend of this site https://github.com/ildebr/store-repository it has a react frontend and a Django backend, auth is made with Django-rest-framework. Originally the database was using PostgreSQL but due to some trouble with my PC, I changed it to SQLite. When I try to register I'm unable to do it, I get an error of 200. I don't know what could be causing trouble cause it should not be having trouble functioning.

When trying to register I get

Internal server error: /auth/users

I already have cors implemented and set like:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000'
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you addding localhost to your

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

If yes try to add 127.0.0.1 to your

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
```

But I see you get an internal server error.

That means you have an error in your code. So I think you may have an error in file that is in use of auth/users. You have to debug your code.

From other site you get error 200. That means that server is working properly. But your frontend code / browser returs error (I prefer to use Google Chrome for development).

peace :)